# Launching Eclipse plug in template

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I created a Eclipse plug-in project by selecting a plug-in template provides by the eclipse. Then i ran the plug-in it opened another eclipse and the plug-in executed there.Why so? is the plugin taking eclipse's application class to create workbench?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an elaboration of "If you want to run the plugin in your main workspace you will have to export the plugin and install it in your main Eclipse." that @greg-449 had in his answer. You can do this.

### Step 1 - Export your plugin

From the File menu, choose Export... and then choose the `Deployable plug-ins and fragments` wizard.

[image: step1]

### Step 2 - Configure your Wizard Options

1. Select the plug-ins you want to export.
2. As the destination, choose `Install into host`
3. Press Finish

[image: step2]

### Step 3 - Confirm unsigned content

As you are probably not signing your plug-in, but you do trust it, say Yes to the Warning: you are installing software that contains unsigned content.

[image: step3]

### Step 4 - Restart Eclipse

Restart Eclipse when prompted to to enable the plug-ins.

[image: step4]

### Result

You should now see your new plug-ins. To make this example I used the new Plug-in wizard and choose the "Hello, World Command" template. The arrows below point to the contributions in the UI that the plug-in made.

[image: step5]

Comment: Another nice walk-through but for some reason this isn't working for me. The jar file is installed in `~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/install/plugins` but the project wizard isn't showing up in the list of C++ Executable Projects after I restart eclipse. Works fine when I do "Run As" from the plugin project.

Comment: Have a look in the error log ~/workspace/.metadata/.log (BTW if the problem was related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092746/creating-a-new-c-project-in-eclipse-cdt-with-the-same-settings-as-another-proj/33180391 it was because of missing `template/` in `build.properties` have a look on github for an update

Answer (score 2):

When you run a plugin (Run As > Eclipse Application) Eclipse starts a new instance of Eclipse including your plugin and uses a new workspace. This enables you to test the plugin without damaging your main Eclipse installation and workspace.

If you want to run the plugin in your main workspace you will have to export the plugin and install it in your main Eclipse.

If you want to run your plugin as part of an RCP you can set the application or product launched in the 'Run > Run Configurations...' entry.

For example:
[image]

Here I am running a product called 'greg.music.e4.rcp.product'

Comment: But how the Plug-in project created as the rich client platform are running stand-alone.

Comment: Added example of running an RCP