# eclipse mars c++ project export library path

Tags: c++, eclipse, export

I am using eclipse mars for a project and I have over 20 libraries that I have in my library list to link against.  Is there a way to export this list so I don't have to type them in every time?

The searches I have done all show an export settings page in the properties but my installation doesn't show that option.  Is there a way to accomplish this or do I have to retype them in every time.

I looked in the .cproject file and thought I could copy and past the list from one project to another, there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This is way harder than it should be, IMO. I finally got help in creating a project template that, in the end, worked pretty well (way better than trying the export/import approach, which I had tried, along with just direct edits of the project files)

Here are the links to the Q&A: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092746/creating-a-new-c-project-in-eclipse-cdt-with-the-same-settings-as-another-proj) and [@Jonah Graham's detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33180391/2587908) (along with his github example) outline the basic ideas of how to do this with a project template. This [Q&A has some follow-up on drop-down options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264161/eclipse-cdt-project-template-setting-drop-down-options). The discussion in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33124968/2587908) also helped.

I found the eclipse documentation on this to be very confusing and had much better luck with Jonah's answer. I downloaded his example, got it to work, and made minimal modifications to get it to do what I needed. I don't think I really modified the example plugins.xml at all. I had a little problem with the build.properties file, which is documented in the linked discussions.

Comment: I looked into the template and it is different enough from the example that I can't get it to work.  I can't see where to set the location for the template and project type. the plugin.xml looks different enough.

Comment: And you are correct.  It seems odd that they took out the settings for what is exported and came up with this.

Comment: I basically downloaded Jonah's example, got it to work, and made minimal modifications to get it to do what I needed. I found the eclipse documentation on this to be very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2) CDT you have the button "Export" (see image) for the projects that reference current one. You can add a reference to another project in the tab "References" (shown in same image).

[image]