# Eclipse Mars - set default settings for C++ project (c++11 set by default)

Tags: c++, eclipse, configuration, eclipse-cdt

I have found from other answers that in my Eclipse Mars CDT I can setup C++11 dialect using:

*Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Dialect -> ISO C++11 (from drop down list)*

and C++11 syntax highlighting using:

*Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> Entries -> GNU C++ -> Add.. (for CDT User Setting Entries) -> Preprocessor Macro: __cplusplus=201103L*

Questrion:
**How to save those properties as default configuration so that when I create new C++ project I will have them already set?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Create a Template

You can create your own template for the C/C++ New Project Wizard. Lots more information in [Creating a new C++ Project in Eclipse CDT with the same settings as another project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33092746/2796832) but here is some extras about C++.

For C++ Use [C++ Hello World Template](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.gnu.ui/templates/projecttemplates/HelloWorldCCProject/template.xml) as a starting point. The key difference between the C++ and [C template](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.gnu.ui/templates/projecttemplates/HelloWorldCAnsiProject/template.xml) (other than the source) is the [`isCProject`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.gnu.ui/templates/projecttemplates/HelloWorldCCProject/template.xml#n44) passed to the `NewManagedProject` process.

### Use the Elevenator Plug-in

Primarily designed to make C++11 default, the [Elevenator](http://www.cute-test.com/projects/cute/wiki/Elevenator) plug-in may resolve your issues. However my answer has a significant hole in that I don't know how to install it on its own as it comes with [Cevelop](https://www.cevelop.com/)

Comment: This is great. Have you come up with a solution to create a template that creates C++ project instead of C project? How to do that.. I specifically want to set C++ dialect and I cannot do this in C project...

Comment: updated answer with some more info to help you along the way. You can use my example I wrote for the other answer to start you off, but you will have to do some digging in your .cproject file to identify which settings you want to change. https://github.com/jonahkichwacoders/example_cdt_template/blob/master/com.example.cdt.templates/template/template.xml