# How can I create a new Eclipse CDT project template?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Whenever I create an Eclipse C++ project I select `Hello World Project` because it automatically creates an `src` folder and an source file. Do you know how I could create a new template where the source file is named `main.cpp`, not `(project name).cpp`?

Comment: Although not technically a duplicate, my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/33180391/2796832 should provide you a good starting point on creating templates.

Comment: @JonahGraham Thanks.