# How to differentiate between build configurations in Eclipse (C) project template to setup build cfg sepcific settings?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-pde

I'm trying to play with Eclipse (C) project template. I found this very descriptive answer of how to [work with Eclipse project template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33180391/5350353) from @Jonah Graham and went through [Eclipse documentation - How to add project templates to CDT](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Ffirstplugin_create.htm)

I'm able to create the project template and setup some settings by "SetMBSStringOptionValue"

```
<!--  Set TMP setting by adding textual build settings -->
<process
    type="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.SetMBSStringOptionValue">
    <simple name="projectName" value="$(projectName)" />
    <complex-array name="resourcePaths">
        <element>
            <simple name="id" value=".*compiler\.option\.misc\.other*" />
            <simple name="value" value="TMP_SETTING_RELEASE" />
            <simple name="path" value="" />
        </element>
    </complex-array>
</process>
```

My question is how do I differentiate between build configurations? E.g. I want to setup different settings for "Debug" and "Release" build configuration. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK no one has provided a "process runner" that allows the configuration to be specified when setting the options.

What you can do is add your own subclass of org.eclipse.cdt.core.templateengine.process.ProcessRunner, basing it on org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.SetMBSStringOptionValue that additionally lets you specify the configuration to apply it to. The Eclipse extension point you need is [org.eclipse.cdt.core.templateProcessTypes](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_cdt_core_templateProcessTypes.html).

Keep in mind when you do that users do a new project wizard they can choose to have/not have Debug/Release configs as shown in this screenshot:

[image]