# Eclipse PDE CDT "template.xml" configuration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-pde, project-template

I'm currently trying to develop a template Plug-in for CDT (C/C++ Development Tooling). The goal is to simply get the needed project structure directly via "New Project" without copying and renaming Files manually.

The Documentation seems to be quite bad on that. But a nice guy explained the most important steps here: [Creating a new C++ Project in Eclipse CDT with the same settings as another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092746/creating-a-new-c-project-in-eclipse-cdt-with-the-same-settings-as-another-proj)

My Problem now is how to exactly configure the "template.xml" file. I just found a single page of a short description: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FprojectTemplateEngine%2FHowtodeveloptemplates.html
I want to configure my template in a way that I have a folder "myFolder" in the New Project Wizard where the Project template "myTemplate" is located.

When I'm right this is what I need, but I don't really know how to use this.

> org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.NewManagedProject: It defines all
>   the parameters required for a new managed project and provides the
>   fully qualified name of the class, which processes these parameters.
>
> Here is a list of parameters defined by this process type:
>
> ```
> Name: You use this parameter to specify the name of the managed project. It is of type simple.
>
> projectType: You use this parameter to specify the type of the managed project. It is of type simple.
>
> location: You use this parameter to specify the location of the managed project. It is of type simple.
>
> targetType: You use this parameter to specify the type of the target binary. It is of type simple.
>
> configs: You use this parameter to specify the build configurations for the managed project. It is of type simple.
> ```

I would be really happy if someone could help me how to create a Folder/type of Project for my template?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I found an interesting extension point, but don't really know how to configure it to do what I need. If someone is able to help me, i still would be really happy! :) https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdialogs_wizards_newWizards.htm